# Resizing button to fit different screen sizes

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make the button below resize depending on different screen sizes but retain the same ratios (i.e. text and button size should change proportionately so they look the same on all screens). I am using the AutoSizeText package to resize the text based on screensize but the text doesn't seem to getting smaller on the smaller screen which might be causing the button to resize oddly.

[![button 1][1]][1] - lager screen
[![button 2][2]][2] - smaller screen

I have tried using a mediaquery to size the button with height and width but that does not seem to be working.

Is there a recommended way of doing this?

```
class PurchaseButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final Product product;

  PurchaseButton({Key key, @required this.product}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double deviceWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0.05 * deviceWidth),

    child: Row(
      children: <Widget>[

    Expanded(
      child: MaterialButton(
//      height: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 6,

        onPressed: () async {
          await Provider.of<SubscriptionModel>(context).makePurchase(product);
        },
        child: Text('Join now! Only ${product.priceString}',
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1.copyWith(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, fontSize: 0.03 * deviceWidth)),

        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      ),
      ),
    ],
    ),
    );
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many ways to do so, here's a suggestion:

**Wrap your widget with this tree of widgets:**

- **Container**: to manipulate the width according to the screen size,
- -- **Row**: we need it to force Expanded to work,
- ---- **Expanded**: will Expand its content to the whole space it has,
- ------[the widget you want to expand]

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  double deviceWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
  double deviceHight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

  Container(
      // If the button size(Row) is 90% then we give margin 5% + 5% like this
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0.05 * deviceWidth),

      // We need a Row in order to "Expanded" to work
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          // Use "Expanded" if you want the button to fill the Row's size
          // Use "Flexible" if you want the button to fit the text inside size.
          Expanded(
            child: MaterialButton(
              onPressed: () {
                print('Hi');
              },
              child: Text(
                'Join now! Only...',
                style: Theme.of(context)
                    .textTheme
                    .body1
                    .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
              ),
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Regarding `AutoSizeText` it takes the size of text's container into consideration, not the screen size, my suggestion is to use regular Text(..) widget with font size taken from `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width`

e.g

```dart
child: Text(
   'Join now! Only...',
   style: Theme.of(context)
          .textTheme
          .body1
          .copyWith(
             fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
             fontSize: 0.03 * deviceWidth,
          ),
   ),
```

Comment: thanks, jehad! - i implemented the code as you said, but now the button is not showing at all - have i made a mistake in interpreting your answer? (updated code in the question to how i have it now)

Comment: In the updated code you are returning empty container `return Container();` look at the end of your snapcode. instead return the container just beneath this line `double deviceWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;`

Comment: Not related to above comment: regarding `fontSize: 0.03 * deviceWidth` maybe you will need to manipulate it to find the best ratio, it hasn't to be 3%.

Comment: ah that was my mistake completely, this works perfect now! thanks! I will try to see which fontsize works best :)